# node-gyp error while installing a nodejs module?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I tried to install steam node module on windows and got an error below 
I think it's an error of node-gyp white configure and run install.js file 
Can someone tell me how can I fix this, I found many question like this but the answers didn't help me anymore. 
Thanks!

> ```
> npm ERR! ursa@0.8.0 install: `node-gyp configure build && node install.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the ursa@0.8.0 install script.
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ursa package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     node-gyp configure build && node install.js
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls ursa
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
> npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
> ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "steam"
> npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\FongZooZ
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! not ok code 0
> ```

Comment: Have you got Visual Studio 2012 installed?

Comment: no, but I have Visual Studio 2013 Premium, have any problem with 2013 version?

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio 2013 was a problem but not anymore: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/339 Normally node-gyp problems on Windows are down to problems with the Visual C++ compiler, that's most likely where your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\" to your path.